# What's the difference between `type private MyRecord = {...}` and `type MyRecord = private {...}`

Tags: .net, f#, functional-programming, record, encapsulation

What's the difference between

```
type private MyRecord =
    { id : int }
```

And

```
type MyRecord = private
    { id : int }
```

From what I read:

- In the first case, the type is private and only accessible within the file.
- In the second case, the type is public but all fields are made private. We can expose the important ones through properties.

Comment: Seems to me you have answered your question. Perhaps you should clarify what more you want to know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the comment indicates, you've got it pretty much nailed. Interestingly, this fact isn't mentioned explicitly in the [F# Language Specification](http://fsharp.org/specs/language-spec/), but could be inferred from the error which will be produced when trying to make a record field private, e.g. `type MyRecord = { private id : int }`

> Accessibility modifiers are not permitted on record fields. Use 'type
>   R = internal ...' or 'type R = private ...' to give an accessibility
>   to the whole representation.

In effect, if you make "the whole representation" private, you cannot construct a record and also not access its fields outside the scope of the accessibility modifier.